# How to use more commands together in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose, portainer

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'

services:
  # Your other service definitions here.

  # Portainer
  portainerservice:
    image: portainer/portainer
    volumes:
      - portainer_data:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_password:/tmp/portainer_password
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"


volumes:
  portainer_data:
```

I need to use two commands, that works separately fine, but how can I use it together?

```
command:  
      # - -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      # - --admin-password-file '/tmp/portainer_password'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to run them as one line:

```
portainerservice:
  image: portainer/portainer
  command: 
      - --admin-password-file '/tmp/portainer_password' -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

You may have good luck in the documentation as well: https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#inside-a-file

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

command: -c 'first_command && second_command2'